# How can I wrap JSON objects I get so I can add properties/methods on them in js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I make API calls that return JSON objects in my react redux application.

Now I find I need to add methods on top of the raw JSON object that I get back to add frontend business logic around those models.

So say I get a User model from my API as a JSON, currently I can only expose the properties that are in the API's JSON object.

I would like to add methods/properties once I get this back from my API.

Is this good practise?  If so, there must be a way to do this for all API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not good practice.  From the [FAQ docs:](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizingstate#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state)

> **Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?**
>
> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.
>
> If you are okay with things like persistence and time-travel debugging potentially not working as intended, then you are totally welcome to put non-serializable items into your Redux store. Ultimately, it's your application, and how you implement it is up to you. As with many other things about Redux, just be sure you understand what tradeoffs are involved.

The `react-redux` framework is heavily based on principles of **functional programming**.  What you're trying to do is much more object oriented.  I would encourage you to read up on the differences between functional programming and object oriented programming.  They are *very* different paradigms.  https://medium.com/@sho.miyata.1/the-object-oriented-programming-vs-functional-programming-debate-in-a-beginner-friendly-nutshell-24fb6f8625cc

If you need functionality on top of your json objects, you should create functions that accept the json object as an argument, and do what you need from there.  If you had more concrete examples of the functionality you require, I might be able to suggest a cleaner approach.